# $(W_1\cap W_2)^{0}=W_1^0+W_2^0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$, then $$(W_1\cap W_2)^{0}=W_1^0+W_2^0$$.

> **Attempt** Suppose $f\in W_1^0+W_2^0$. Then $f=f_1+f_2\in W_1^0+W_2^0$ ,where $f_1\in W_1$ and $f_2\in W_2^0.$
> Now for $z\in (W_1\cap W_2)$, $f(z)=(f_1+f_2)(z)=f_1(z)+f_2(z)=0+0=0$.
> Therefore, $f\in (W_1\cap W_2)^0$. Thus $W_1^0+W_2^0\subseteq (W_1\cap W_2)^0$.

How to prove this part $(W_1\cap W_2)^0\subseteq W_1^0+W_2^0$.

Let $f\in (W_1\cap W_2)^0$ then $f(z)=0$ for $z\in (W_1\cap W_2)$.

How to proceed next?

Any hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try making a dimension argument instead of double inclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** -   **Theorem** If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are finite dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V$, then $W_1+W_2$ is finite dimensional and $$\operatorname{dim}W_1+\operatorname{dim}W_2=\operatorname{dim}(W_1\cap W_2)+\operatorname{dim}(W_1+W_2)$$.

Proof of the above theorem gives an idea to complete the proof of your problem.